# Problems Implementing a Premade Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would first like to state that I started learning HTML 5 days ago, and therefore I am very new to everything.

I am trying to implement the code given here: http://jsfiddle.net/NFXzn/9/.

But for some reason the dropdown menu is blank. I have uploaded my code here: http://gbrowse2014.biology.gatech.edu/viru.html

Since I did not make the code, I am assuming the problems lies with how I implemented the code (specifically the javascript). I have narrowed the problem down to one particular function:

```
$.each(g_Vehicle, function(index) {
var iYear = g_Vehicle[index].Year;
if ($.inArray(iYear, g_YearsArray) == -1) {
    g_YearsArray.push(iYear);
}
});
```

I am using firefox, and I have gone through www.w3schools.com to look for implementation tips, but I have not corrected the problem.

On a sidenote, does anyone know how to change the code to use the dropdown-checkboxes instead of the dropboxes?

Comment: Your question is not very specific which is probably why it's getting downvoted. What about it is not working? What are you expecting to happen that isn't happening? From what I can tell that block of code that you posted as the problem is working perfectly. I opened the console and checked the value of g_YearsArray and it's `["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013"]` which is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That loop is working fine. The problem is that you're running the code before your `select` is loaded, so nothing is being appended to the page. Either wrap your code in `$(document).ready( function() { ... });`, or move your `<script>` blocks to the bottom of the page (after the HTML has completely loaded).

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

(On the top-left corner of the jsFiddle page, you'll see a dropdown which displays `onLoad` -- which is automatically doing that job for you. Your page as it stands is the equivalent of `No wrap - in <head>` -- not what you want.)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was missing.